# ng-packagr with secondary entry point

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I got an error while building the source code using ng-packagr with Secondary Entry Points.

My project structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUT6a.png)

I followed the guide from official repo `https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/main/docs/secondary-entrypoints.md` but I got the following error:

```
Building Angular Package

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'ngx'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
✔ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
✔ Writing FESM bundles
✔ Copying assets
✔ Writing package manifest
✔ Built ngx

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'ngx/src/animations'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
✖ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
error TS6053: File '/Projects/ngx/src/animations/src/public_api.ngtypecheck.ts' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation
error TS6053: File '/Projects/ngx/src/animations/src/public_api.ts' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! base-angular@0.0.1 build-ngx: `ng build ngx --configuration production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the base-angular@0.0.1 build-ngx script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/truongtran/.npm/_logs/2022-12-02T09_56_16_832Z-debug.log
```

I tried to fix but still have any idea.